# struggling to understand a sentence with であろうとしていない

Tags: grammar, nuances, anime

I was watching 弱キャラ友崎くん 2nd STAGE episode two with Japanese subs and I could not understand this after all of my searching. This is because I need to learn more about grammar and given time, studying and input I'd probably come to understand but it's really annoying me right now haha.

Full-sentence: そして現状平林さんはゲーマーであろうとしていない

So, I know that `〜たりとも〜ない`is a thing and i don't fully understand that either but an example I would is one I found here: `1人としていない` = `There is not even one person`. So, `1 + counter + として (...ない)` is a grammatical pattern that means (`not) even one`. However, I couldn't get around to how this would work with  `としていない` due to the `い`. The reason I can't find an answer is becuase everywhere explains it how I just mentioned, `〜たりとも〜ない`, but this makes me wonder what the bit in between this is. An idea I had was that `い` was `いる` Or showing that it's in the present but surely not haha. Again, I know I could better understand this after studying other stuff related to this, but I would like to understand a tiny bit now.

At first with the context I thought the character was basically saying that 平林さん isn't a gamer but it's a bit more nuanced. I heard that `であろう` is also kind of like `だろう` but I'm not sure.

Google and the subs say that it's `平林さん isn't trying to be a gamer`　which makes some sense but it still confuses me a bit. Where is the `〜たくない` Wouldn't gaming be `いる` as well? so why is it `あろう`? Is this `あろう` separate from `ある?` Sorry, a lot of questions in one haha

Thanks!!

Comment: check the grammar ようとしている https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43013/what-is-the-use-of-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b

Answer (score 2):

This is the grammar point:   verbようとする.  This means to "attempt to"

So, to say,

> ゲーマーであろうとしていない

is indeed to say

> 平林さん is not trying to be a gamer.

This grammar is the volutional form of the verb plus とする and is an important point of grammar.

Here であろう is the volitional form of である which is a bit literary/formal form of だ.

We can break this down a bit more:

> 平林さんはゲーマーだ

> Hirabayashi is a gamer.

I'm not sure why you expected to see 〜たくない.  This would add the meaning of "not want to".  So, you could say

> 平林さんはゲーマーになりたくない

> Hirabayashi doesn't want to be[come] a gamer.

Or possibly,

> 平林さんはゲーマーであろうとしたくない

> Hirabayashi doesn't want to attempt to be a gamer.